# How to generate Country then Province then City then ZipCode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am running a project, on the registration stage
i want user to be able to select first Country, then have a chance to get the province, city, and zip code.
But the problem is that some countries do not have province, which means that after "country" selection there should be a city dropdownlist.
Is there any API, from google maps... or anything else?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I smell JavaScript here.

Here is a nice article:

[Cascading DropDownLists with jQuery and ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/97/Cascading-DropDownLists-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET)